# B splines recursion

Tags: functional-analysis, recursion, spline

Given that by definition the *i-th* B-spline of order *k* is:
$$B_{i,k}=w_{i,k}B_{i,k-1}+(1-w_{i+1,k})B_{i+1,k-1}$$

where $w_{j,k}=\frac{x-t_j}{t_{j+k-1}-t_j}$

We can define the spline space as 
$$S_{k,t}:=\{\sum_i\alpha_iB_{i,k}:\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}\} $$

The author pointed out that $$\sum_i\alpha_i B_{i,k}=\sum_i(\alpha_i w_{i,k}+\alpha_{i-1}(1-w_{i,k}))B_{i,k-1}$$ 
but honestly I don't really get how to arrive to this expression, using the recursion I am able to obtain:
$$\sum_i\alpha_i B_{i,k}=\sum_i(\alpha_i w_{i,k}B_{i,k-1}+\alpha_{i}(1-w_{i+1,k})B_{i+1,k-1})$$ which is nothing like the desired result.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions coincide:
$$
\begin{split}
&\phantom{=}\ \sum_i(\alpha_i w_{i,k}B_{i,k-1}+\alpha_{i}(1-w_{i+1,k})B_{i+1,k-1}) \\
&= \sum_i(\alpha_i w_{i,k}B_{i,k-1}+\alpha_{i-1}(1-w_{i,k})B_{i,k-1}) \\
&= \sum_i(\alpha_i w_{i,k}+\alpha_{i-1}(1-w_{i,k}))B_{i,k-1} .
\end{split}
$$

Comment: but why is $\alpha_{i}(1-w_{i+1,k})B_{i+1,k-1}=\alpha_{i-1}(1-w_{i,k})B_{i,k-1}$?

Comment: It is not. The equality is achieved when summing over all possible $i$. For instance $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}c_i=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}c_{i-1}$.

Comment: In both series the same terms are appearing, just *shifted*.

Comment: You are right, don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks